# router-link does not create links properly in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2, vue-router

I want to create simple links to components via `Vue-router` plugin.

For that I created a `routes.js` file like this :

```
import VueRoute from 'vue-router';

let routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: './components/Home'
    },
    {
        path: '/About',
        component: './components/About'
    }
];

export default new VueRoute({
    routes
});
```

And there is `app.js` file like this :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import axios from 'axios';
import router from 'routes';

window.Vue   = Vue;
window.axios = axios;
Vue.use(VueRouter);

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

And this is my master page content :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
    <title>My First Laravel Vue App </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">

    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
    <router-link to="/About">About</router-link>

</div>

<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But After compiling all js files when I open page,`router-link` does not work and just creates a simple empty html comment instead.

I do not know what is problem and how Can I solve that.

**Update:**

I changed `import router from 'routes';` to `import router from './routes'` and all things worded fine!

Comment: isn't it `import VueRouter from 'vue-router';` ?

Comment: @Pradeepb, Yes, it is.

Comment: I meant in `routes.js` file.  Even after correcting it, it does not work for you?

Comment: As you can see it is at beginning of `routes.js` file. even after correcting it does not work.

Comment: What I see is `VueRoute` instead of `VueRouter`.

Comment: it was a typo. I correct it but problem not solve.

Comment: is it required to add `import VueRouter from 'vue-router'` to both `app.js` and 'routes.js' files?

Answer (score 4):

you have everything setup but fforgot the `router-view`

Add it like this:

```
<body>
<div id="app">

    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
    <router-link to="/About">About</router-link>

    <router-view></router-view>
</div>

<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

The matched routes are rendered in the [router-view](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-view.html)

**EDIT**

The `component` property of the route object should be the component itself but you are passing it a string

So do it like this:

```
    import VueRoute from 'vue-router';

import Home from './components/Home'
import About from './components/About')

let routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/About',
        component: About
    }
];

export default new VueRoute({
    routes
});
```

Comment: I followed  [Vue SPA Essentials: Routing](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/26)  from *laracast* series. there, does not used `<router-view></router-view>` and all things worked properly.

Comment: even after adding `<router-view></router-view>` , problem does not solve.

Comment: is it different than `component: require('./components/Home')`? I used `require()` but does not solve.

Comment: No , any errors. no in compiling no after running the page. only always a `;` character appears in page.

Comment: @A.B.Developer did you add the `router-view` inside the div with `id='app'` ?

Comment: Yes, I added it. another thing that there is in the page load is that : `Home` and `About` words appear but quickly removed.

Comment: @A.B.Developer could you produce a jsfiddle so that the problem can be debugged, because when i run the same code in my environment I see no problems and its working fine